# Can I configure NUnit to execute on trimmed assemblies?

Tags: .net, deployment, msbuild, automated-tests, nunit

I have a .NET app which is published with [assembly trimming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trim-self-contained). I recently had a nasty bug caused by missing code in the trimmed output, which would have been mitigated had the automated tests executed on the trimmed code.

Is there a way to make NUnit run on the "published" (i.e., trimmed) output of the project? My CI/CD pipeline uses `dotnet test` as the test runner, so it needs to run as part of the `VSTest` msbuild target.

Comment: can you explain the bug in detail with examples?

Comment: @MuratIshen, the bug is irrelevant; I have solved the bug. I am asking how to build a trimmed NUnit test project.